# Is this sentence stylistically correct? (not grammatically)

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs, style

I need to run this sentence by y'all.

> The candidate stood out in aspects like class participation and interaction with classmates.

I have never read "stand out" being used in that way. Can you say that someone stands out ***in*** certain ***activities***?

Am I right in my suspicion? If I am, what would be a good alternative?

Comment: This usage is common. See [stand out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand+out) "2. To be conspicuous, distinctive, or prominent."

Comment: Yes, but have you ever read a sentence like "He stands out *in* a certain activity?

Comment: If *the candidate can stand out **in** a crowd*, s/he can stand out in other aspects as well!

Comment: They're hardly the same thing. A crowd is the group of people in which she stands as different. An aspect, on the other hand, is a field. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: From COCA:  This portable, at-home simulator ***stands out in three ways:*** It's fun (tee it up on digital versions of Torrey Pines, Kiawah and the Old Course). It's useful (instant swing analysis of clubhead speed, face angle, path and tempo). And it's simple to useall you need is a computer, your clubs, and high ceilings.

Comment: You can stand out in a field. Farmers do it all day. Seriously though, to my ear that sentence is a little clunky, but the use of "stand out" is perfectly fine. When it comes to class participation, *the candidate* stood out - they were noticeably better at class participation than most of their classmates. (Or noticeably worse.)

Answer (score 1):

This statement seems awkward. I would phrase it instead as:

> The candidate stood out in certain aspects, like class participation and interaction with classmates.

although that still sounds a bit mawkish to my ear. I might instead just say:

> The candidate stood out in class participation and interaction with classmates.

which employs more direct language.